# Graph start from the middle to downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have used the Multiple axis highchart graph to plot on my page. Kindly help me to fix the grey colour bar graph should start from the $0 (middle) to downwards.

[image]

Below are the code snippet :-

```
 Highcharts.chart('cashFlowChart', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
            backgroundColor: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: false,
        subtitle: false,
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jul 2021', 'Aug 2021', 'Sep 2021', 'Oct 2021', 'Nov 2021', 'Dec 2021', 'Jan 2022', 'Feb 2022', 'Mar 2022', 'Apr 2022', 'May 2022', 'Jun 2022', 'Jul 2022'],
            crosshair: false
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                format: '${value}',
                style: {
                    color: 'rgb(102, 102, 102)'
                }
            },
            title: false,

        }, {
            title: false,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: false
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'left',
            x: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 0,
            floating: false,
            itemMarginBottom: 25,
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Inflow',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 0,
            color: '#23C770',
            data: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 78850.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 80.00],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '$'
            }


        }, {
            name: 'Outflow',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            color: '#8AA2B2',
            data: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 8553.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 36100.00],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '$'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Net Change',
            type: 'spline',
            color: 'rgb(28, 37, 44)',
            data: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 70297.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, -36020.00],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '$'
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                lineColor: 'rgb(28, 37, 44)',
                lineWidth: 1,
                fillColor: '#ffffff'
            }
        }]
    });
```

Kindly help me to fix this and I have used yAxis to 0 and 1 for the column to start from the middle but it won't help to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/75Lkt6gx/ - the grey columns start from the bottom of the chart because they are assigned to a hidden axis.

You should use only one y-axis and define `min` and `max` properties.

```
yAxis: {
    ...,
    min: -100000,
    max: 100000
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0wgmhcry/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min